# Parse JSon List from webapi [frombody]

Tags: c#, arrays, json

I have a json array that comes from webapi [fromBody].

my class is something like this:

```
    public class SalesBOMComponent
    {
        public string BILLOFMATERIAL { get; set; }
        public string BOMITEMNODENUMBER { get; set; }
        public string BOMCOMPONENT { get; set; }
        public string BOMCOMPONENTDESCRIPTION { get; set; }
        public string COMPONENTQUANTITY { get; set; }
        public string COMPONENTUOM { get; set; }
        public string INDICATORSPAREPART { get;set; }
    }

    public class SalesBOM
    {
        public string BILLOFMATERIAL { get; set; }
        public string MATERIALPARENT { get; set; }
        public string PLANT { get; set; }
        public string BOMUSAGE { get; set; }
        public string ALTERNATIVEBOM { get; set; }
        public string VALIDDATE { get; set; }
        public string BASEQTYPARENT { get; set; }
        public string BASEUOMPARENT { get; set; }
        public string BOMSTATUS { get; set; }
        public List<SalesBOMComponent> BOMCOMPONENTS { get; set; }
    }

    public class Product
    {
        public string MATERIALPARENT { get; set; }
        public string DESCRIPTION { get; set; }
        public List<SalesBOM> BOMSALES { get; set; }
    }
```

I would like to get value from BOMCOMPONENT (under class SalesBOMComponent) and Plant (under class SalesBOM).

however, the method read from [fromBody] using c#

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] Product inputdata)
    {
        string result = string.Empty;
        string currentDate = string.Empty;
        string ErrorMessage = string.Empty;

        string MaterialParent = string.Empty;
        string MaterialDescription = string.Empty;

        MaterialParent = inputdata.MATERIALPARENT;
        MaterialDescription = inputdata.DESCRIPTION;
```

how to achieve that?

Comment: I'm using c# @AndrejKesely

Comment: What error or what problem do you have? Can you show the code that you have tried so far?

Comment: @Serge : I want to get the value from BOMComponent (Under class SalesBomComponent) and also the value from Plant (Under class SalesBOM). those value are under array. I don't know how to deserialize it as the json not under string, instead comes from [fromBody]

Comment: there is not BOMComponent  for example, there is a list of BOMComponent. So what do you want to get value from?